# How to configure Orphaned Items Strategy in MultiBranch project to delete (prune) disabled (deleted) branches without repository scanning? (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I'm trying to configure my Jenkins MultiBranch project so that immediately deletes disabled branches after a respective repository event.

For this purpose, I configured the "Orphaned Items Strategy" with "Discard old items" checkbox enabled and an empty field "Days to keep old items".

With such a configuration, it deletes disabled branches only after the Scan Multubranch pipeline action. Is it possible to somehow configure the "Orphaned Items Strategy" feature without the whole MultiBranch project scanning?

For example, if a branch is marked as disabled, immediately delete it from the Jenkins project.